# QGIS rasterize does not cover full polygon

Tags: qgis, rasterization

When I rasterize my polygon, it does not cover the upper part, as well as a small part in the bottom right. What is the reasoning for this, and how do I change it?[image]

I rasterized the following way:
[image]

Comment: does anyone have any other ideas? much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the "Output Raster Size Units" parameter to georeferenced units instead of pixels

Comment: I tried, but this doesn't make a difference

Comment: What is the range of values ​​of the "SEASONAL" field?
If it contains any 0's, try changing the no-data value to some other value outside the range of "SEASONAL" field

Comment: all 379 features have the value 1 for seasonal